# UITableViewCell reloadData method not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The reloadData does not work.

Code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
allOnMapButton.hidden = YES;

volLocApp = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startParsing) withObject:nil];

total = [volLocApp.volListArray count];

[super viewDidLoad];
 }


- (void) startParsing
{
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startIndicator) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];   

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"Link"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

// 2 -- parsing
parser = [[MyParser alloc] init];

[parser parseXML:data];
[data release];
[parser sortTheArray];

[parser print];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[pool release]; 

 }

 - (void) startIndicator
 {
av.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[av startAnimating];
  }

- (void) updateTable
{
allOnMapButton.hidden = NO;
[av stopAnimating];
[myTable reloadData];   
 }
```

What is wrong in above code? The reload method does not work. If I go back and return to this view then only data is displayed.

Comment: I presume your `updateTable` method is being called? If so, how are you setting up `myTable`? (i.e.: Are you sure it's the same table that you're referring to in the `updateTable` method?)

Comment: yeah....if I go back n return to this view than only data is displayed..

Comment: Have you configured the `dataSource` property of `myTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your myTable has been defined through an IBOutlet, and correctly linked to your table view. If nothing happens with no errors, this is usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

can u post your code in some git repo?
there may be several causes fir that
try setNeedsDisplay for your table's super view
and u can also try perform selector on main thread rather than background
to see if any differences. Usually the view updation is on main thread only
and that may be an issue